# Removing child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an AJAX chat application that constantly gets new data and appends it to a div (#container) in the form of another div (.child). Multiple .child's can be inserted per second, but I only want to keep the most recent 10. Every time a download occurs, I call the following function:

```
function cleanup(){
        var current = $('#container');
        var allData = current.children();
        if(allData.length > 10){
            for(var i = 0;i<allData.length-10;i++){
                allData[i].remove();
            }
        }   
    }
```

This works, but it lags horrendously. I have to switch my current tab just to see the css work correctly. Am I doing something wrong?

I cannot change the data flow, as the chat depends on getting all the data that is sent. I am just looking for the most efficient way of deleting old elements.

**Example:**

If I had 30 children in my div, the first 20 children would be `.remove()`'d and only the last 10 would remain.

Comment: why not just limit the the data coming or limit your query?

Comment: It is a chat system so limiting the data would invalidate the purpose.

Comment: just do `clear` and `fetch` then

Comment: Have you proven to yourself (by profiling for example) that this message removal is the issue? And that it is not being called pathologically? If so, exactly how complicated are these children - because this is a pretty quick operation.

Comment: The children are just a div with 2 divs containing text inside of them. They are quite simple, actually. However, when I comment the inside of the function, all the lag is gone, so I came to the conclusion that this was the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than letting some code add divs and the cleanup function clean it up afterwards - which if I understand you correctly, could add a whole bunch of children, not just one - why not have effectively a queue of length 10 in memory, and keep pushing things on (and popping them off the back once you reach 10+ items), and then set those children on your #container periodically.

This way you are always going to get the latest 10 elements, but you can update the container at a rate that makes sense (and therefore reflow the visual document a a rate that makes sense).

This could be on an interval, or you could even do it every time you process a message - but the point is, you are not adding to the document, reflowing it, then removing from it again. That seems like an inefficient way to approach the problem.

Comment: While I agree with you, the application requires receiving messages as soon as they sent, otherwise, it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I believe with this approach you will still get the desired behaviour. If you are going to make the chat messages invisible anyway, why not never set them in the first place (and imagine, for example, getting 1000 messages in a split second - the user can't read them fast enough anyway).

Comment: The idea is that the chat messages contain sensitive material, so after they are read, they are destroyed. A user would never receive more than 5 messages in a second. Otherwise I would use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:lt()` selector to limit to target last divs( as :lt selector is zero index based):

```
 $('#container .child:lt('+$('.child').length-11+')').remove();
```

also its better to replace the content rather than appending new one.

Comment: Wouldn't newly added elements have a positively incrementing index?

Answer (score 0):

CSS Solution:

```
#container:nth-of-type(10) ~ #container {
    display: none;
}
```